# How to represent boolean algebra strings?

Tags: java, boolean

I'm looking for a solution to represent boolean algebra.
Let's say I have a lot of String objects that I'm displaying to the user. He can now multi-select them (make an `&& AND` connection between them), and also make `|| OR` connections. The final expression should also be shown to the user.

So, eg if he selects `String1, String2, String3` I want to present `String1 && String2 && String3`. And maybe lateron the user should be able to build expressions like `(String1 || String 2) && String 3`.

My question is: how could I track reference on these boolean selections between the string objects?
Of course I could just create a String expression; and always append what he selected. But what if he deselects an object? Then I would have to parse the whole string an revaluate it.

I'm searching for something to keep a `AND/OR` reference between the objects and then having a method to build the String final expression based on these.

Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: You can try [Apache Jexl](http://commons.apache.org/jexl/). Then store object in `Map` with id. And then write expresion string were you will reference ids from `Map`.

Comment: is it something like when you give it an input "(True AND False) OR True" it will return boolean true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just need a [tree structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29).  Every inner node represents an operator (`&&`, `||`, etc.), and every leaf node represents a term.

---

See also: [*abstract syntax tree*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by [Lexical Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis). There are many lexical generator for java like: JavaCC , JLex etc.

Or you can use something like pre/post -fix calculator or stack calculator for parenthesis balancing and to maintain the hierarchy, originally it is done by [traversing through a "tree"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) and in that calculator in place of "1"-"9" numbers (which comes as string) you have to match "true" or "false" and in place of "+", "-" binary operator you have to match and operate "and" and "or"!

I have made a Boolean Algebra Parser as I have committed in my previous comment, I think it works, you are also welcome to fork and contribute:
https://github.com/sadaf2605/Java-Boolean-Algebra-Parser

code:

```
public class BooleanAlgebra {

    static final String CONST_and="And";
    static final String CONST_or="Or";
    static final String CONST_true="True";
    static final String CONST_false="False";


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(booleanAlgebra("False")==false);
        System.out.println(booleanAlgebra("True")==true);

        System.out.println(booleanAlgebra("False And False")==false);
        System.out.println(booleanAlgebra("True And False")==false);
        System.out.println(booleanAlgebra("True And True")==true);
        System.out.println(booleanAlgebra("False And True")==false);

        System.out.println(booleanAlgebra("(False And True)")==false);
        System.out.println(booleanAlgebra("True Or (False And True)")==true);
        System.out.println(booleanAlgebra("(True And False) And (False And True) Or True")==true);

        System.out.println(booleanAlgebra("( (True And False) Or True )")==true);

        System.out.println(booleanAlgebra("( False Or (True And (False Or True)) Or True )")==true);




    }




    static boolean booleanAlgebra(String str){
        return TrueFalse(str, false, "Or");
    }


     static boolean TrueFalse(String s,boolean b, String op){
        boolean btemp=false;
        s=s.replaceAll(" ", "");

        while(!s.isEmpty()){

            if(s.startsWith(CONST_true)){
                btemp=true;
                s=s.substring(4);
            }else if(s.startsWith(CONST_false)){
                btemp=false;
                s=s.substring(5);
            }else if(s.startsWith(CONST_and)){
                op=CONST_and;
                s=s.substring(3);
            }else if(s.startsWith(CONST_or)){
                op=CONST_or;
                s=s.substring(2);
            }else if(s.startsWith("(")){
                int end=s.indexOf(")");
                if(end>0){
                b=TrueFalse(s.substring(1, end>-1?end:1),b,op);
                s=s.substring(end);
                }
            }else{
                s=s.substring(1);
            }
            if (op.equals(CONST_and)){
                b=b&&btemp;

            }else if(op.equals(CONST_or)){
                b=b||btemp;
            }   
        }
        return b;   
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious! Concerning your question: yes the overall intention is finally to return `boolean` (in the backend) of the conducted expression.

Comment: Using the index of the closing parenthesis doesn't handle nested parenthesis.

Comment: tyvm! I'll try to look deeper into this the following days and see if I can benefit from it.

Comment: thankyou @AndyClaw, I was missing an if else condition! Bug fixed!